# Help with closed-form solution for system of non-linear equations

Tags: conic-sections, closed-form, nonlinear-system

This is my first question here, so hopefully I will be able to explain my problem in a coherent way. My ultimate question is: do you see any way I can simplify the following system so I can have a more intuitive solution to it? Let me explain in details what I mean:

I want to characterize $x,y,z$ that solve the following system of non-linear equations:

\begin{align}
\Delta x &= \frac{\theta\Delta z\Delta y}{\Delta y-\theta\Delta z}\tag{EQ1}\\
\Delta x+\Delta y+\Delta z&=\overline{Y}\tag{EQ2}\\
\theta\left(\Delta z\right)^{2}+\left(\Delta y\right)^{2}&=\overline{U}\tag{EQ3}
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
\Delta x &=x-\overline{x}\\
\Delta y &=y-\overline{y}\\
\Delta z &=z-\overline{z}
\end{align}

and $0<\theta<1$, $\overline{Y}$, $\overline{U}$, $\overline{x}$, $\overline{y}$ and $\overline{z}$ are parameters.

The way I've approached this was to parameterize (EQ2):
\begin{align}
\Delta y+\Delta z&=\alpha
\end{align}
such that $\alpha=\overline{Y}-\Delta x$

For $\theta=0.8$, $\overline{x}=\overline{y}=\overline{z}=0.5$ and $\overline{Y}=-0.5$ and $\overline{U}=0.2$ this parametric system would look like the following (I apologize I don't have reputation to embed the photo here):

[The parametric system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmvS.jpg)

I can characterize $\Delta y$ and $\Delta z$ as a function of $\alpha$:
\begin{align}
\Delta y=\frac{\theta\alpha \pm\sqrt{\overline{U}(1+\theta)-\theta\alpha^{2}}}{1+\theta}\\
\Delta z=\frac{\alpha \mp\sqrt{\overline{U}(1+\theta)-\theta\alpha^{2}}}{1+\theta}
\end{align}

My problem arrives in the characterization of $\alpha$ using (EQ1). Although we can show such an $\alpha$ exists, it is far from an intuitive closed-form characterization, as $\alpha$ solves:
\begin{align}
\pm\frac{(\overline{Y}-\alpha)(1-\theta)\sqrt{\overline{U}(1+\theta)-\theta\alpha^2}}{\theta\alpha\pm\sqrt{\overline{U}(1+\theta)-\theta\alpha^2}}&=\theta\left(\alpha\mp\sqrt{\overline{U}(1+\theta)-\theta\alpha^2}\right)
\end{align}

Am I using the correct approach to this problem? Or do you see anyway I could simplify this? Thank you!

Comment: you want to solve your System for $x,y,z$?

Comment: Yes, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. I want to characterize $x,y,z$ in terms of parameters.

Comment: can we denote $$\Delta x=a$$ etc, then we must not write so much, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, I did that. I have defined $\overline{Y} -\Delta x=\alpha$, as you can see in my parameterization presented after the attached picture.

Comment: ok after this i have got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will reason in terms of the $\Delta$ rather than the non-centered $x,y,z$.

The first equation, which can be written
$$\Delta x\Delta y=\theta\Delta z(\Delta x+\Delta y)$$

is that of a cone with apex at the origin. The second is a plane and the third and elliptic cylindre of vertical axis. The latter two define an ellipse, which you can represent by the parametric equations

$$\Delta y=\sqrt{\overline U}\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2},\\
\Delta z=\sqrt{\frac{\overline U}\theta}\frac{2u}{1+u^2},\\
\Delta x=\overline Y-\Delta y-\Delta z.$$

(The rational expressions can be obtained from the trigonometric representation.)

Plugging these expressions in the first equation, you will get a quartic equation in $u$, which can have zero, two or four solutions  (intersection points of the ellipse and the cone).

It is unlikely that there will be a simple expression for these solutions, even though there are only three independent parameters and the quartic equation is not fully general.

Comment: Thank you, @Yves. The transformation you mentioned for (EQ1) was quite useful for I could "see" this is cone. I was missing that. I am glad you have mentioned that you don't think I can indeed find simple expressions for these solutions. I was thinking I was not being able to do it, but it was there, somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

is this right now?
$$a=\frac{\theta bc}{b-\theta c}$$
$$a+b+c=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\theta c^2+b^2=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$a=x-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$b=y-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$c=z-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is a redefined version of my problem problem if you take $\Delta x=a$, $\Delta y=b$, $\Delta z=c$ and if we define $\theta=0.5$, $\overline{Y}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\overline{U}=\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: so then lets solve it

Comment: for the variable $x$ we get the equation $$1200x^4-1000x^3-495x^2+600x-127=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @Dr. Sonnhard Grauber. I upvoted your question but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: for me is it enough, that i could help you Laura, a nice weekend